# Sort a list of objects into groups in C#

Tags: c#, list, nested-lists

I have a list of 'tickets' and each 'ticket' contains three numbers. I would to sort all the tickets into groups so each group contains tickets which share at least one number in common. How do I sort this data into a final list of grouped tickets?

In short here is the initial list of tickets:

```
ticketA = { 1, 2, 3 }
ticketB = { 3, 4, 1 }
ticketC = { 5, 6, 7 }
ticketD = { 7, 8, 5 }
ticketE = { 9, 10, 11 }
ticketF = { 11, 1, 9 }
```

The resulting output would be (broken into seperate lines for ease of reading visually:

```
GroupedTickets = {
    <List>( ticketA, ticketB, ticketF ticketE )
    <List>( ticketC, ticketD )
}
```

Below is the snippet of code I've been using to figure out a solution for...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CrowdTool
{
    class Ticket
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Sort();
        }

        public void Sort()
        {
            List<Ticket> allTickets = new List<Ticket>();
            Ticket ticketA = new Ticket();
            ticketA.Numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
            allTickets.Add(ticketA);
            Ticket ticketB = new Ticket();
            ticketB.Numbers = new List<int> { 3, 4, 1 };
            allTickets.Add(ticketB);
            Ticket ticketC = new Ticket();
            ticketC.Numbers = new List<int> { 5, 6, 7 };
            allTickets.Add(ticketC);
            Ticket ticketD = new Ticket();
            ticketD.Numbers = new List<int> { 7, 8, 5 };
            allTickets.Add(ticketD);
            Ticket ticketE = new Ticket();
            ticketE.Numbers = new List<int> { 9, 10, 11 };
            allTickets.Add(ticketE);
            Ticket ticketF = new Ticket();
            ticketF.Numbers = new List<int> { 11, 1, 9 };
            allTickets.Add(ticketF);

            // variable to store groups of tickets
            List <List<Ticket>> GroupedTickets = new List<List<Ticket>>();
            foreach (var ticket in allTickets)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ticket);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As stated, your specification does not appear solvable. What if tickets A and B share a member, B and C share a member, but A and C do not share a member? Should A and C be in the same group? Note that an example, or even many examples, does not a **specification** make.

Comment: In your example, shouldn't tickets E and F be together due to the shared 11?

Comment: @PeterDuniho is right! you can not achieve this until you want to have one ticket list in more than one groups. So, you should specify exactly why do you need this. That might be helpful in providing better solution.

Comment: You are correct @JaredMoore they would be. I corrected the example.

Comment: @PeterDuniho is correct in his statement. If A and B share a value and B and C share a value. They would be all grouped together.

Comment: _"They would be all grouped together"_ -- so, you have a "group" in which A and C, which share _no_ common elements, are still in the same group? Bizarre.

Comment: Wouls Only in a group if B existed. Otherwise A and C have no relationship to one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I've taken the approach of making all the groups - for all ticket numbers. The final results can then be queried to get you what you want.

I had to change the data into a form that suited the processing. I started with this:

```
var tickets = new Dictionary<string, int[]>()
{
    { "TicketA", new [] { 1, 2, 3 } },
    { "TicketB", new [] { 3, 4, 1 } },
    { "TicketC", new [] { 5, 6, 7 } },
    { "TicketD", new [] { 7, 8, 5 } },
    { "TicketE", new [] { 9, 10, 11 } },
    { "TicketF", new [] { 11, 1, 9 } },
};
```

Now I can do this query:

```
var groupedTickets =
    tickets
        .SelectMany(t => t.Value, (t, n) => new { t, n })
        .ToLookup(x => x.n, x => x.t)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            number = x.Key,
            tickets = x.Select(y => new
            {
                ticket = y.Key,
                numbers = y.Value
            }).ToList()
        })
        .ToList();
```

Now that gave me the results like this:

[image: grouped tickets]

But that's not terribly easy to see the whole thing, so I reformatted like this:

```
1: TicketA = {1, 2, 3}, TicketB = {3, 4, 1}, TicketF = {11, 1, 9} 
2: TicketA = {1, 2, 3} 
3: TicketA = {1, 2, 3}, TicketB = {3, 4, 1} 
4: TicketB = {3, 4, 1} 
5: TicketC = {5, 6, 7}, TicketD = {7, 8, 5} 
6: TicketC = {5, 6, 7} 
7: TicketC = {5, 6, 7}, TicketD = {7, 8, 5} 
8: TicketD = {7, 8, 5} 
9: TicketE = {9, 10, 11}, TicketF = {11, 1, 9} 
10: TicketE = {9, 10, 11} 
11: TicketE = {9, 10, 11}, TicketF = {11, 1, 9}
```

You should be able to query against `groupedTickets` to get precisely what you want.

For example, you could do this:

```
var output =
    groupedTickets
        .Where(x => x.tickets.Skip(1).Any())
        .Select(x => String.Join(", ", x.tickets.Select(y => y.ticket)))
        .OrderBy(x => x)
        .Distinct();
```

Which will give you this output:

```
TicketA, TicketB 
TicketA, TicketB, TicketF 
TicketC, TicketD 
TicketE, TicketF
```

And this is quite similar to the output requested, but formatted for display purposes.

---

Based on the question edit and the comments below here is an updated solution.

```
var lookup =
    tickets
        .SelectMany(t => t.Value, (t, n) => new { t, n })
        .ToLookup(x => x.n, x => x.t.Value);

var groupedTickets =
    tickets
        .SelectMany(t => t.Value, (t, n) => new { t, n })
        .OrderBy(x => x.n)
        .ToLookup(x => x.n, x => x.t)
        .SelectMany(
            x => x.SelectMany(y => y.Value),
            (x, y) => new []
            {
                Tuple.Create(x.Key, y), 
                Tuple.Create(y, x.Key)
            })
        .SelectMany(t => t)
        .Where(t => t.Item1 != t.Item2)
        .Distinct();

Func<
    IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>>,
    IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>>,
    int,
    IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>>> fold = null;
fold = (ts0, ts1, n) =>
    n == 0
        ? ts0
        : ts0
            .Concat(fold(
                ts0.Join(
                    ts1,
                    t0 => t0.Item2,
                    t1 => t1.Item1,
                    (t0, t1) => Tuple.Create(t0.Item1, t1.Item2)),
                ts1,
                n - 1))
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray();

var pairs = tickets.SelectMany(t => t.Value).Distinct().Count();

var final =
    fold(groupedTickets, groupedTickets, pairs)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
        .ThenBy(x => x.Item2)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2)
        .GroupBy(x => String.Join(",", x), x => x.Key)
        .Select(x => x.SelectMany(y => lookup[y]).Distinct());
```

This produces the two distinct sets:

```
{ { 1, 2, 3 }, { 3, 4, 1 }, { 11, 1, 9 }, { 9, 10, 11 } }

{ { 5, 6, 7 }, { 7, 8, 5 } }
```

Comment: this is almost exactly what i was looking for. As mentioned above though, if any of the 3 numbers are found, they should be considered in the same group. I corrected the list.

TicketE should be included in the same group as TicketA, TicketB, TicketF

Comment: So how would I modify your example to achieve that.

Comment: @JokerMartini - So you're looking to make groups of tickets that are connected by a thread of common ticket numbers. So, `{ 1, 2 }`, `{ 2, 3 }`, and `{ 3, 4 }` would all be part of the same group because the `2` joins the first two and `3` joins the next two, thus bringing all three together. Is that right?

Comment: you are seemingly on the right track with the direction you were heading

Comment: @JokerMartini - I have a solution that works, but I had to go out before I could get a chance to post it. It's tested and works well. Can you let me know if the output you're expecting is a `List<List<List<int>>>` or `List<List<string>>`?

Comment: The first list is correct since it would be containing the following information. 
`List<List<List<int>>>` which translates to `AllGroupedTickets > TicketsPerGroup > Ticket > IntegerList`

Comment: @JokerMartini - Yes, it's working, but I didn't get a chance to post. I'll be able to do so later today - probably about 6 hours from now.

Comment: Looks like you have nailed it. Thank you very much. This was a brain twister for me.

Comment: @JokerMartini - It really was quite a twister. The recursive `fold` function was the best.

Comment: Yeah i couldn't wrap my head around this one. I tried many ideas neither which worked. It's sad this got voted down so much. I think its a great questions and amazing solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not very optimized, but this will do the job and you can improve upon it for efficiency (most obviously with the .Clear() and .AddRange()).

```
var tickets = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>()
{
    { "TicketA", new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 } },
    { "TicketB", new List<int> { 3, 4, 1 } },
    { "TicketC", new List<int> { 5, 6, 7 } },
    { "TicketD", new List<int> { 7, 8, 5 } },
    { "TicketE", new List<int> { 9, 10, 11 } },
    { "TicketF", new List<int> { 11, 1, 9 } },
};

var newDict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>(tickets);
foreach(var ticket in newDict)
{
    bool madeChange = true;
    while(madeChange)
    {
        var groupTickets = newDict.Where(t => t.Key != ticket.Key && t.Value.Intersect(ticket.Value).Any() && t.Value.Except(ticket.Value).Any()).ToList();
        madeChange = false;
        if (groupTickets.Any())
        {
            var newSet = groupTickets.SelectMany (t => t.Value).Union(ticket.Value).Distinct().ToList();                
            ticket.Value.Clear();
            ticket.Value.AddRange(newSet);
            foreach(var groupTicket in groupTickets)
            {
                groupTicket.Value.Clear();
                groupTicket.Value.AddRange(newSet);
            }
            madeChange = true;
        }
    }
}

newDict.GroupBy (t => String.Join(",", t.Value)).Dump();
```

Essentially, it will look for all tickets with a matching number. It will then insert the numbers into *all* tickets which match. It repeats this until no new numbers are found.

Comment: ill test this out in the morning. From what you are saying it sounds like a nice approach.

Comment: @JokerMartini change the last line to `var res = newDict.GroupBy (t => String.Join(",", t.Value)).Select(l => l.Select(k => k.Key));`